# QSharedData and operator=

Tags: c++, qt, qshareddata

Recently I wanted to implement implicit sharing functionality like Qt does with its `QSharedData` and `QSharedDataPointer` classes, so I took a look at their sources and in the place of `QSharedData` I found these three lines:

```
private:
    // using the assignment operator would lead to corruption in the ref-counting
    QSharedData &operator=(const QSharedData &);
```

However I don't understand how could `operator=` break reference counting.

If I just did not make it private and left its implementation empty, wouldn't it serve the same purpose ?

i.e. if I wrote simply this:

```
    public:
    QSharedData &operator=(const QSharedData & ) { return *this; }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole purpose of `QSharedData` is to maintain a reference count.  If you assign one to another, what should happen to the reference count on each side?  As you have correctly determined: nothing.  It simply makes no sense to assign one `QSharedData` to another, and therefore the sensible course of action is to prevent it at compile time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is basically what I thought, I just wanted to have
it confirmed that there is not any hidden catch.

Answer (score 2):

No it would be a bad thing, if it is doing reference counting it needs to do book-keeping and just having it return `this` would mean there are copies of `QSharedData` unaccounted for. this [example from the C++faq](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/ref-count-simple.html) shows basically what kind of book-keeping is needed for `operator =` in a reference counted object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry to respond late, I was reading through the faq
you linked in (you have my upvote for this).
My point was, as Dan mentioned too, that `QSharedData` is basically a base class,
which disables assignment operator, but that does not prevent inherited class
from defining its own `operator=`, which in turn means, that we only want to prevent
the reference count from being copied. And this is what I wanted to have confirmed,
that there is nothing unexpected going on.